# Java - Get variable from Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashmap

I created a variable (HashMap) in Application, this variable change value and size when a Bean in Application run. But when I call this variable at a controller then this variable size not change.
Please help me explain why this variable not change size at controller and how can I fix.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static Application app;

    public Application() {
        app = this;
    }
    public HashMap<Integer, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<Integer, Socket>();
    public HashMap<Integer, Socket> getSockets() {
        return sockets;
    }

    public void setSockets(HashMap<Integer, Socket> sockets) {
        this.sockets = sockets;
    }

    ....

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(TaskExecutor exec) {
        ...
        sockets.put(Integer.valueOf(socket.hashCode()), socket);
        System.out.println("size: " + sockets.size());
        //>> 1
        ...
    }
}
```

TestController.java

```
@Controller
public class NotificationController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        HashMap<Integer, Socket> sockets = Application.app.getSockets();
        System.out.println("size: " + sockets.size());
        //>> 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never do this again:

```
public Application() {
    app = this;
}
```

the `this` pointer is not fully initialized when used in constructor. This will lead to unexpected behavior.

To access `sockets` in your `Controller`, you have some options:

1. Make it static. (This is not good at all)
2. Create a `@Component` or `@Service` wrap that `sockets` map and update them via `@Autowired`

   ```
   @Component
   public class SocketWrapper {
       public HashMap<Integer, Socket> sockets = new HashMap<Integer, Socket>();
       public HashMap<Integer, Socket> getSockets() {
           return sockets;
       }

       public void setSockets(HashMap<Integer, Socket> sockets) {
           this.sockets = sockets;
      }
   }
   ```

And in your configuration class

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(TaskExecutor exec, SocketWrapper wrapper) {
   // Modify wrapper.getSockets()
}
```